# struts2, Invoke session variable method with static parameter

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, permissions, ognl

I don't know if my Permission Checking is right but I'm doing it this way.

```
public class User {
   public boolean hasPermission (String permission){
       // codes here to check from Roles.permissions if permission parameter exists
       // return true if exists, otherwise return false
   }
}
```

In my JSP, I want to hide a button if the User which is saved in the session as "currentUser" doesn't have 'save.settings' permission.

to organize my codes, I declared an interface:

```
public interface Permission {
    public static final String SAVE_SETTINGS = "save.settings";
}
```

so that I will just access the static variable in my JSP when checking for permission.

now how do i do this in my JSP?  I tried...

```xml
<s:if test="{#session.currentUser.hasPermission(@my.pkg.Permission@SAVE_SETTINGS)}">
     <div>
        <input id="iSave" type="button" value="Save" /> 
    </div>
</s:if>
```

but it doesn work.

```xml
<constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true"/>
```

is also set in my struts.xml

Any idea guys?

Comment: As a sanity check, if you use `<s:property>` to view the static var, does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```xml
<s:if test="#session['currentUser'].hasPermission(@my.pkg.Permission@SAVE_SETTINGS)">
```

or

```xml
<s:if test="#session.currentUser.hasPermission(@my.pkg.Permission@SAVE_SETTINGS)">
```